# Can I just keep adding more filter stages to a power supply?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, noise, passive-filter, split-supply

I need to power an [AD8429](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8429.pdf) instrumentation amp with USB power. 5v from the USB is used to power a DC-DC converter to get +-5v out. The datasheet provides a recommended filter with a table of L and C values.
[image: MTU1S0505MC recommended filter]

10uH and 4.5uF for the [MTU1S0505MC](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8807030456350/kdc-mtu1.pdf?1583754812000).

What's not clear to me from the diagram is whether there should be an LC filter on each rail (+5v and -5v) or if it should be one filter with the inductor on the +5v rail and the capacitor coupling to the -5v rail. Which is the proper wat to implement this recommended filter?
[image: Is this a better filter schematic?]

If I want a less noisy output, can I just add more stages to this filter or could there be consequences to that?
One consequence I can think of is added output impedance, since the inductors will have some real resistance. I'm not sure how much this matters in my application.

Comment: mainly increased output impedance. if you keep R low, you will struggle with resonances instead. if you want to combine low impedance with strong PSRR, you will either need a *lot* of output capacitance to damp the resonance (problems with Startup, though) or an active solution, i.e. a linear post-regulator, where low frequencies are dealt with by feedback and high frequencies are taken care of by a much more benign LC filter.

Comment: wrt to filters on one rail or both: you should decouple both to output common for low differential mode output noise. you should also provide a low impedance route from the output to input to return common-mode switch currents.  e.g. two caps from out+/- to output common and another cap from common to in- (~1nF is enough usually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output filter interacts with the DC converter, so loading the output with more filters isn't necessarily a good idea at least without some care.

However, especially for a ~80 kHz switching frequency (which is relatively low and thus hard to filter), a common approach is to use LDO in addition to a filter.  The advantage of this approach is that the LDO attenuates very low frequencies as well, not just the switching frequency.  For example, if you picked the +/- 9v version of that converter and put (to pick a random part) an ADP7118 on the positive rail, the PSRR would be:

[image]

This gives you *at least* 80dB of rejection at the switching frequency *and below*. Not bad for a $2 part, and you can do better if you look a little harder.  Pick something similar for the negative rail and you can make a very quiet supply from a noisy source.